# Скачать xml по ссылке .php

Tags: php

Есть ссылка на файл - site.ru/export.php (**updated:** к содержимому php доступа нет)
По этой ссылке формируется xml файл, если по ней перейти xml открывается прямо в браузере.
Задача - скачать файл средствами php себе на хостинг.
Файлы .xml с других источников скачиваю просто

```
copy($url, $file);
```

Этот файл так не скачать.
Подскажите как правильно это сделать, пожалуйста!
**Уточнение:** Мне нужно скачать файл xml к себе на сервер со стороннего сервера. Файл там формируется средствами php и ссылка site.ru/export.**php**. При ее открытии в браузере формируется xml файл. Как его скачать средствами php на мой сервер?

Comment: $url = "site.ru/export.php";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('file.xml',$str);

Comment: да, открывается в браузере

Comment: Попробуйте в файле export.php добавить в конце кода, но перед любым выводом в браузер _(если есть вывод)_ эту строку: `header("Content-type: text/xml");`

Comment: @Эдуард я не имею доступа к php файлу. мне просто надо скачать xml который формирует этот файл.

Comment: этот header там прописан. сервер отдает HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 09:12:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=windows-1251
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php    

         $xls = 
         "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
         <note>
         <to>Tove</to>
         <from>Jani</from>
         <heading>Reminder</heading>
         <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
         </note>";

         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=XMLFile.xml");
         header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Expires: 0');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
         header('Pragma: public'); 


         print_r($xls); 

?>
```

---

**Update**

```
<?php    

       $file = "https://site.kz/file-xml.php"; //$_POST['link'] $_GET['link']

    if (!empty($file)) { 

         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=XMLFile.xml");
         header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Expires: 0');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
         header('Pragma: public'); 

         print_r(file_get_contents($file)) ;

    } 

?>
```

---

**update 0.1**

```
<?php    
      $file = "http://hadleybags.ru/bitrix/catalog_export/partner.php"; //$_POST['link'] $_GET['link']

    if (!empty($file)) { 

         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=XMLFile.xml");
         header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Expires: 0');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
         header('Pragma: public'); 

            $xml_data = file_get_contents($file);

            $ch = curl_init($file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

    }  
?>
```

Comment: я видимо криво вопрос задал =) Я так понимаю, вы пишете код, который должен быть на стороне, которая отдает файл. У меня нет туда доступа. У меня есть ссылка на php, который отдает файл.

Comment: Ссылку в студию

Comment: @DmitryUvarov обновил ответ

Comment: https://hadleybags.ru/bitrix/catalog_export/partner.php

Comment: @DmitryUvarov работает.

Comment: @DmitryUvarov Первый вариант тоже работает просто поменяйте https на http

Comment: Да, замена https на http помогла! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Справедливости ради, если поменять https на http работает даже copy($url,$file); =)

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли `http://`  в `$url` добавить

```
$url = "http://site.ru/export.php"; 
$str = file_get_contents($url); 
file_put_contents('file.xml',$str);
```

Comment: это не работает. в моем коде был http

Comment: Что конкретно из этого не работает? В переменной `$str` не попадает xml ?  Или в файл не записывается?

Comment: У меня выводит ошибку "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" при попытки открыть url

Comment: Ну, как бы http://site.ru/export.php - это всего лишь пример урла. Результатом того, что вы написали является пустой файл file.xml весом 0 байт., т.к. file_get_contents($url) содержит только false

Comment: https://hadleybags.ru/bitrix/catalog_export/partner.php

Comment: вот реальная ссылка

Comment: Подставил реальную ссылку  - все работает. Какая у вас ошибка?